# Autres choses / d'autres choses

Tags: sens, usage, locutions

Bonjour/Bonsoir/Bonne nuit à toutes et à tous !

Quelle est la/les différence(s) entre "**autres choses**" et "**d'autres choses**" ? Existe-t-il des différences d'usage ? Pareil pour le singulier.

Ici on trouve les deux phrases qui apparemment veulent dire la même chose.

---

https://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/traduction/d%27autres+choses.html

Exemples :

entre autres choses adv—   among other things adv - inter alia adv (Latin)

parmi d'autres choses adv— among other things adv

passer à autre chose v —move on v

---

Merci de votre attention !

Answer (score 1):

Je ne vois pas de différence de sens entre les « **autres chose** » des deux expressions traduites par *among other things*.

Il y a une différence de forme due au fait que seule la deuxième expression utilise la préposition « **de** ».

***Entre autres choses***, qui est à la fois plus courant et plus littéraire que ***parmi d'autres choses*** n'utilise pas de préposition, probablement à cause de la locution figée ***entre autres*** qu'il inclut.

***Autre chose***, lui, est clairement singulier. Il signifie *something else*, pas *other things*,

> Je pense à autre chose. (une seule chose)

> Je pense à d'autres choses. (plusieurs choses)

Answer (score 0):

**I**

"D'autre choses" might insist on the elements that can be considered as  additional when those elements are understood to be of the sort that has been talked about, of a sort that is expected, whereas "autre chose" does not necessarily imply that. At times the two forms are interchangeable. It is sometimes difficult to draw the line between the two usages. I'll provide next examples of typical contexts, which, despite their number, will still not be enough to get a confortable understanding.

- Est-ce qu'il y a **d'autres choses**  dans le camions ? (*"Autre chose" could also be used here.*)
- Vous allez donc déménager au moyen d'une camion que vous prête la firme. Est-ce qu'il y aura  **autre chose** que vos possessions dans le camion, je veux dire, par exemple des outils appartenant à la firme ? (*"d'autres choses" can also be used.*)
- Vous lui avez parlé de vos ennuis; est-ce que vous avez mentionné **autre chose** ? (*Only "autre chose"*)
- Nous avons parlé de tous les sujets que vous avez étudiés je crois, certains dans les sciences naturelles et d'autres  faisant partie de la technologie… s'il n'y a pas **autre chose** passons à quelques informations concernant vos loisirs.
- Il n'y a plus de travail pour nous dans ce domaine, alors nous devons penser à faire  **autre chose**. (*Only "autre chose"*)
- Ils ont construit de grands ouvrages publics, des ponts, des barrages, mais ils feront **d'autres choses** encore. (*Her,  clearly the idea of "being additional" is the relevant one, so "autre chose" is not good diction.*)
- Pourquoi te disputes-tu avec ton frère ? À cause de cette bicyclette ? Eh bien, s'il n'y a pas **autre chose**, arrêtez de vous disputer, vous aurez chacun votre bicyclette demain. (*Here it is impossible to use "d'autre chose".*)
- Qu'est-ce qui aurait pu le motiver ? La jalousie, un intérêt matériel ? Vous voyez **autre chose** ? (*"D'autres choses" is not possible here; however, you could say "Vous pensez à **d'autres** possibilités ?".*)
- Changez-vous les idées, pensez à **autre chose** et bientôt vous irez mieux. (*"D'autres choses" is improper here, it makes for mediocre diction.*)
- ([réf.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=ngSihHV72mgC&pg=PT105&dq=%22d%27autres+choses+que%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjvmc71ybzsAhUHxoUKHXp3AUk4ZBDoATBPegQIIBAC#v=onepage&q=%22d%27autres%20choses%20que%22&f=false)) Elles peuvent souhaiter bien **d'autres choses** que son bonheur : elles peuvent souhaiter le voir devenir un homme plus riche et plus important, elles peuvent souhaiter le voir épouser une jeune fille parée des avantages que confèrent l'argent,
- ([réf.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=99QupcxJgaYC&pg=PT33&dq=%22d%27autres+choses+que%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjvmc71ybzsAhUHxoUKHXp3AUk4ZBDoATBXegQIERAC#v=onepage&q=%22d%27autres%20choses%20que%22&f=false)) Elle disait également bien **d'autres choses** que le vieil homme était seul à comprendre. Dans le marécage où le vieillard leur apprit à suivre les sentiers qui évitent les trous d'eau et de vase, il y avait tout un univers à découvrir. Les grenouilles… (*Here "autre chose" would induce the reader to elicit that the matter is not "additional things" but a wholly different thing"; therefore, "**autre chose**" is possible but the meaning is changed.*)